Unable to restore a deleted user with graph API
I am trying to restore a deleted user via graph API. I am following the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-restore?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
I have created an azure application and add User.ReadWrite.All application permissions and already authorize the app with global admin. I have generated the access token and I can see User.ReadWrite.All permission exists in the token roles.
When I request POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/deletedItems/{user-id}/restore I get below response.
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2024-05-20T06:55:15",
      "request-id": "43e68cc6-9b45-4625-8fcc-e88cb4353ce9",
      "client-request-id": "43e68cc6-9b45-4625-8fcc-e88cb4353ce9"
    }
  }
}

I even tried with adding Directory.ReadWrite.All application permission to the app, but failed with the same error. I have verified the deleted user object is exists with GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/deletedItems/{user-id} and it's exists. What I am doing wrong here? Any other permissions or headers to add?

As mentioned in this MS Doc, for app-only scenarios and in addition to being granted the User.ReadWrite.All application permission, the app must be assigned a higher privileged administrator role. Try assigning User Administrator role to the application and run query again.

Have you added the required permission in order to execute delete operation? Also, how olderly deleted user you are trying to restore?

Initially, I registered one application and granted User.ReadWrite.All permission of Application type as below:

Now, I generated access token using client credentials flow via Postman like this:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

Response:

When I tried to restore the deleted user with this token, I too got same error as below:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/deletedItems/userID/restore

Response:


As mentioned in this MS
Doc,
the app must be assigned a higher privileged administrator role to
restore deleted users along with User.ReadWrite.All application
permission for app-only scenarios.

In my case, I assigned User Administrator role to the application like this:
Go to Azure Portal -> Microsoft Entra ID -> Roles and administrators -> User Administrator -> Add assignments

When I generated the token again after role assignment and ran POST request, I got the response successfully:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/deletedItems/userID/restore

Response:

If the deleted user has any directory role assigned, the app must be assigned with higher privileged role like 'Global Administrator' than that deleted user.
Note that, you can only restore users that are deleted 30 days ago, as they will be deleted permanently after that.
Reference:
Working with users in Microsoft Graph - Microsoft Graph v1.0 
